# Fill first listview item static and all other from database

Tags: android

My current code is:

```
content = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).connectDB(MY_DB, TABLE, ID, FIELD, ID, null);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content));
```

I want to add first item to listView manually and then populate all the next items from database.

I have tried to make `content.add(0,"String");` before calling the connectDB but it results to an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code it is pretty simple. Here's some hardcoded stuff as an example of what you might do.

```
public List<String> getMockDataFromDatabase() {
  List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
  itemList.add("Item 1");
  itemList.add("Item 2");
  itemList.add("Item 3");
  itemList.add("Item 4");
  return itemList;
}

public void setupListAdapter() {
  List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
  itemList.add("New First Item");
  itemList.addAll(getMockDataFromDatabase());
  listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, itemList));
}
```

The reason why I re-create the list is that if you just add it as a header view it will not be retained when the activity goes awhile, while the ListView will internally retain the Adapter and thus the items in it.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Thank you. In my case i omitted the getMockDataFromDatabase() and instead added content and voila! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a header view and apply it to your list view, this will accomplish the same thing, but keep your arrayadapter code neat and clean (for db content fetching only).

```
content = ((MainActivity)getActivity()).connectDB(MY_DB, TABLE, ID, FIELD, ID, null);
TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity());
tv.setText("lorem ipsum");
listView.addHeaderView(tv);
// then normal array adapter set
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, content));
```

More info :

- [addHeaderView (View v, Object data, boolean isSelectable)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)
- [addHeaderView (View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View%29)

Comment: Useful answer. Didn't know i can do that. @David 's answer was exactly what i needed in my case.

Answer (score 0):

```
List items = new ArrayList();

//some fictitious objectList where we're populating data
for(Object obj : objectList) {
    content.add(0,"String");
    items.add(1, obj);
    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

try this: see at 0 we added our string, and then at 1 we populated our listview data.