# Add an entry with own layout at the first position in a listview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I'm using a ListView to display the posts in a thread, if I scroll the list all the way up it should show a TextView or similar where I can choose the pagenumber. If I scroll down the TextView should move up like every other entry in this list.

The TextView must have a different layout.

Comment: what the actual question?

Comment: "How could I do this?"

Comment: Use header view like in this answer, I hope this helps you:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19524280/794088